# Python wordlist

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to compare the input letters(dictionary) with the list(textfile with words) and print the words matching the inputed letters. What have I done wrong?(I know i only have a print YES or NO-function if it finds a matching word at the moment. What's the best way to create this function by the way?).

```
def ordlista(list):
    fil = open("ord.txt", "r")
    words = fil.readlines()

    list = []

    for w in words:
        w = w.strip()
        list.append(w)
    return list


chars = {}
word = raw_input("Write 9 letters: ")

for w in word:
    w = w.lower()
    if w not in chars:
        chars[w] = 1
    else:
        chars[w] += 1


if chars.keys() in ordlista(list):
    print "YES"
else:
    print "NO"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chars.keys()` is a list, so

```
chars.keys() in ordlista(list):
```

will never be True. What you want is match the letter counts against each word in your list. So I'd suggest

```
charsum = sum(chars.values())
for word in wordlist:
    if len(word) == charsum and all([(word.count(c) == chars[c]) for c in chars]):
        print "YES for word '%s'" % word
```

EDIT: If you want those words to match which have *at least* the letter counts (i.e. a word with 3 a's will match an input of two a's), then you'll have to change the `==` to a `>=`.

EDIT2: Since you want exact matches, the easiest solution would be to count the number of chars and make sure the word has that length.

Comment: Yes, that's almost it! But as you can see it's also displaying words containg other characters. I just want it to print, if lets say there's a word "lov".

    Write Letters: ovl
    YES for word 'ovlig'
    YES for word 'ovningsledare'

Comment: Im a new user so therefore I dont have the reputation to upvote you just yet ;)... I will get back to you tomorrow!

Comment: Maybe I should explain what the program is all about. The user types in 9 letters and the program will print the words formed (which are in the txt-file) by exactly these letters which only can be used once each.  What the code does now is to print every word containing the inputted letters. And if I it would count the length it would only print a couple of words. This is the main concern. 

Every word also has to contain the inputted letter with index [4]. But that's a later problem I guess?

Answer (score 2):

You are checking for the presence of the entire list of keys in your character list, rather than checking for each key individually.  You must iterate over your keys individually, and then check for their presence.

```
for k in chars:
    if k in ordlista(list):
        print "YES"
    else:
        print "NO"
```

If you want to print the words which consist solely of the letters in your character list, you may use the following approach.

```
for word in ordlista(list):
    if not filter(lambda char: char not in chars, word):
        print word
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes it iterate. But I would like it to find the whole words(in the list) consisting of letters inputed into the dictionary (the words can not contain any other letters, beside some of the ones in dict).

Maybe I have to rewrite some code? But how should I do it? Im very new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html):

```
chars = set(raw_input("Write 9 letters: "))

for word in ordlista(None):
    if(set(word) == chars):
        print "YES for '%s'" % word
```

BTW, the argument `list` to `ordlista` is unnecessary, as it is not used. I would also advise against using the name `list` in general, because it hides the built-in `<type 'list'>`

**Update**: I have read your comment on jellybean's post. If every letter can only be used once, you can obviously not use sets!